# Animated Text for a PDF

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I've seen decks that are PDFs during presentations where type on the same page transitions. For Example: Page opens with a sentence -  "Hi, my name is Ann" and then a few second later another line appears below saying "and this Mike."

I have been trying to figure out how to get this dynamic quality in deck. Can it be done through InDesign or are these created in a different program entirely? If it can be done using ind. - anyone know how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most of it can be done using InDesign, but you may use Acrobat for finishing touches.

There are two fundamental possibilities how that animation has been made.

a) If the document was shown in Fullscreen mode, there would have two pages, the first one with the first part of the sentence, and the second one with the added second part. For the second page, a Page Transition has been set, which runs when switching from the first page to the second one. This scenario is rather easy to implement in InDesign, and may only need Acrobat to properly configure the Fullscreen properties and the page transitions.

b) The parts of the sentences are in form fields, and the second field gets shown after a given time. There is the Acrobat JavaScript method `app.setTimeOut()` (and its terminating method `app.clearTimeOut()` ), which would be used to delay the show of the second field. This, of course would require more work in Acrobat, and also some little Acrobat JavaScript knowldedge.